# Удаление и запись с помощью awk (linux)

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Есть текст (супер обычный, многострочный, разделён пробелами), который сохранен в случайном файле формата .txt. Как можно удалить из этого текста, например, пятое слово из каждой строки и вывести обратно в этот

```
{
i = 3
size = NF
while (i < size) {
    printf "%s ", $i
    $i = ""
    i++
}}
```

Comment: Тут код для конкретной моей задачи, мне просто не понятен сам принцип удаления и обратного вывода в файл

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8019617/4827341